# Using Dire in Clojure gives me gets me ClassNotFoundException generate_catch_predicate

Tags: clojure

Can anyone figure this out? I copy and pasted this from another file, where it works fine. I can't imagine what is causing a problem here.

This is the entire file, it simply masks another file:

```
(ns dedupe-regression-test.supervisor-stop
  (:require
   [dedupe-regression-test.stop :as stop]
   [dire.core :as dire])
  (:use
   [dedupe-regression-test.problems]
   [dedupe-regression-test.errors]))

(dire/with-handler  #'stop/stop
  "A catch all for the problems that arise on stop. We re-throw with the intent of killing the app -- there is probably no point continuing if there was an error on stopup."
  Object
  ;;; 'e' is the exception object, 'args' are the original arguments to the task.
  (fn [e & args]
    (error e ~@args)))


(defn stop []
  (dire/supervise #'stop/stop))
```

And then the function "error":

```
(defn error
  [e & args]
  (doseq [x args]
    (timbre/log :trace (str " type of arg:  " (type x))))
  (if (= (type e) Exception)
    (stack/parse-exception e)
    (timbre/log :trace (str " non-exception error object:  " e))))
```

And I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dire/core$generate_catch_predicate$fn__347
    at dire.core$generate_catch_predicate.invoke(core.clj:239)
    at dire.core$supervised_meta.doInvoke(core.clj:257)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at dire.core$supervise.doInvoke(core.clj:266)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at dedupe_regression_test.supervisor_stop$stop.invoke(supervisor_stop.clj:19)
    at dedupe_regression_test.core$stop.invoke(core.clj:15)
    at dedupe_regression_test.core$_main$fn__11065.invoke(core.clj:26)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dire.core$generate_catch_predicate$fn__347
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

This same code seems to work elsewhere, so I can't imagine what the problem is here. Maybe that the name space and the function name are the same? "stop/stop".

I guess I can change that as a test.

Comment: And you are sure that your leiningen project.clj (or its boot twin) has a dependency on dire at all?

Comment: Sure, Dire works in all other locations in the code.